# query file uri with content resolver?

Tags: android

I have the following simple code that I use to investigate the orientation of an image .

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION }, null, null, null);
```

When the photoUri is a content uri i.e. starts from content:// the cursor is retrieved fine. I get a contentUri when i select an image from the gallery.

However when the photoUri is a fileUri i.e. starts from file://a/b/c.jpg (which happens when i capture an image from the camera) the cursor is null .

What gives ? I am really confused on the situation .

Comment: That's the normal expected behaviour. What's your question ?

Comment: Well , I want to be able to query a fileuri too . I need to obtain a cursor from a picture defined by a fileuri too . Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**answering to the comment:**

You can't. `MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION` is a database column stored in the `content://` database. The `file://` database does not contain such a column, so you can't query it.

**answering the question:**

To extract orientation, android have the native `ExifInterface` class: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
```

Comment: That clears it up a little . One last bit . I was actually using ExifInterface earlier . However I heard that it doesn't work proper on most devices and works just on some. Hence I reverted to the cursor technique . You think its safe to use Exif?

Comment: not really. There're quite a few bugs on it. But I believe the `content://` DB generates its data from the `ExifInterface` anyway. I know from experience that the Picasso library (http://square.github.io/picasso/) handles orientation perfectly, maybe you should check their source code to see how they do.